# Firefox opens many processes - cant mute audio

Tags: windows-10, firefox, audio, browser, volume-mixer

I dont know since when this is happening but Firefox is opening alot of processes and every process can appear in my volume settings

[Image of my mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7NBo.png)

If I mute these processes and open a new tab with audio, the mute of the processes will be ignored and audio is playing (most of the time).

Is there a way to bind all the audio to one process again? or any addons to mute everything?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that every time you create a new tab in firefox, then a new volume mixer processor added.

To enable or disable multi-process Firefox, do the following

1. Type about:config in the browser's address bar
2. Confirm that you will be careful
3. Search for browser.tabs.remote.autostart
4. Double-click on the preference
5. Set it to False
6. Do the same for the other browser.tabs.remote.autostart2

You can refer to
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1358372